# Double summation in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I've got a (beginners)question about matlab. I have tried several things (e.g.: write it as a vectorized loop or write it as an 'if-loop' and compute the sum explicitly), but I keep making mistakes and therefore, I keep getting errors in matlab.

I have to maximize the following function:

```
\sum_{i=1}^{L} \sum_{k=1}^K (r_k^3 t_{ik})
```

with L, K, r_k known. Also, t_ik are desicion variables, so they have values in {0,1}.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing a double for loop:

```
result=0;
for i=1:L 
   for k=1:K 
      result=r(K)^3*t(i*k)+result ;
   end 
end
```

However I believe that your problem is not related to matlab, you just dont know how to convert from maths to code.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems I misformulated my question... However, I just found the solution to my real problem, but as this is a correct answer to the question, I'll mark it as the right one. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

If you're seeking a more vectorized result, you can create the products within the summation by [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), then [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) over the entire matrix to get your answer (à la Adam Farabaugh).  Your equation in LaTeX form looks like this (easier for me to read):

[image]

It looks like `t` is a 2D matrix while `r` is a vector.  With the above statement, it looks like you are taking each row of `t`, and multiplying this row in an element-by-element fashion with `r` with each element in `r` raised to the third power.  You repeat this for all of the rows in `t`, then sum up the results.  Assuming that `r` is a row vector, and the amount of columns in `t` matches the number of elements in `r`, do something like this:

```
prods = bsxfun(@times, r.^3, t);
result = sum(prods(:));
```

The first statement will take `r` and creates a matrix where each row of this matrix will be a copy of `r` raised to the third power.  This is a consequence of `bsxfun`, which is short for **Binary Singleton EXpansion FUNction**.  In a nutshell, it replicates whatever dimension(s) of the variable that has the smaller dimensions between the two, and replicates the elements so that both variables match in size.

We then take this new matrix and do an element-by-element multiplication with the matrix `t`.  Once we do this, we simply sum over all of the elements in this matrix.  You can nest `sum` calls like what Adam suggests, but if you really want to make it more general, you can simply **unroll** the matrix so that it's a single vector, then apply `sum` on this single vector.

Answer (score -2):

If anyone comes looking, the correct way to do this is

```
sum(sum(a))
```

where a is your matrix.  This scales to more dimensions as well.

Comment: Though this is technically correct, this doesn't apply to the question.  There are three separate vectors that require summing over, rather than a matrix.

Comment: Then concatenate them into one matrix and use my method.  It seems like your problem is very vectorizable, in the future if you post the code you have tried you will get answers targeted more to your situation.

Comment: You can't simply concatenate the vectors together and apply `sum` over the rows.  It won't compute the right results.  See my answer.